# Have a composite index with four fields, need to use three

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following index:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX (first, last, age, gender)
```

Age is a nullable field.

I also have two queries that I run:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE first=x and last=y and age=z
```

And:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE first=x and last=y and age=z and gender=w
```

How would I make sure that both queries use the same index? Is there a way to pass a 'fake value' or something so it always returns true, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE first=x and last=y and age=z and gender=*
```

This way it could automatically use the 4-index I've created. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You can check [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) execution plan to see if both queries are using the index

Answer (score 0):

The keys in indexes are used from left to right.  All your conditions are equality, so both should use the index.

MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) has a good explanation of how indexes are used.

Comment: how do you know / or why would it use that index in the first condition, if `gender` is part of the key but it's not supplied?

Comment: @DavidL . . . That is how indexes work.  I included the link to the documentation.

Comment: @DavidL MySQL will execute an "index range scan" (`ref`, `range`) in both cases. When you don't supply the last column value, the range will be wider.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks -- when you say "equality", does it matter if I use either of `is null/not null` or `in ('x','y','z')`? Are those both considered equality?

Comment: @GordonLinoff this seems to be wrong in practice. After I ran the query, it did not use the index at all, and took about several minutes to run on the "3 of 4" query. `explain` showed it was using a different index.

Comment: @DavidL . . . The choice of index is made by the optimizer.  You would really have to test the code with only the one index to see if it works.  I'm surprised that another index would be used, when this is available, because it seems like the best index.  Wait, this is MySQL.  So perhaps I'm not so surprised that the wrong index is chosen.